# Python dict keys as statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, conditional-statements

Was wondering if something like the following was possible:

```
rarity = {>= 75: 'Common', <= 20 : 'Rare', >= 5: 'Legendary'}
```

Comment: I think you may be looking for an Enum

Comment: I can *guess* what you're trying to do here, but please spell it out a bit more.

Comment: What about numbers >=5 and <=20, what do you want there?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: so for 10, both the second and last conditions are true?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7 this will raise a syntax error. It feels like abuse of *dictionary* (key-value storage) concept. Maybe you should rework your code and you could use `'Common'`, `'Rare'` as keys and values as ranges, i.e. `range(5,20)`, `range(20)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with `dict` in python. You probably need an ordinary function for your task:

```
def check(x):
    if x >= 75:
        return 'Common'
    if x <= 20:
        ...
```

Remember that order of checks and `return` statements matters.

Comment: the question is very unclear but there are ways to use a dict like this e.g. `x = 6; {x >= 75: 'Common', x<= 20 : 'Rare', x>= 5: 'Legendary'}[True]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands except OP has made a mistake, for Rare it should be `x>=20` and if you use that in your code you'll see only the last true condition will be returned. So your code will fail for `x=25`

Comment: @anishtain4 We can only guess what the question is about but assuming a single output for a single integer input (also assumed in Ivan's code), it could be done in a dict like I showed above

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes, this is a very poorly written question. However it's clear that OP is looking for a short form of switch. I don't see any reason for a switch command generally, `if ... elif` does the same job.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a way to do this with better than O(k) performance, where `k` is the number of keys in your sort-of dict.

If you are not seeking `dict`'s O(1) performance, and just want a `dict`-like syntax, you can implement a mapping object yourself, like so:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping

class CallDict(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, *pairs):
        self._pairs = pairs
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(())
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._pairs)
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        for func, value in self._pairs:
            if func(x):
                return value
        raise KeyError("{} satisfies no condition".format(x))

# Conditions copied directly from OP, but probably wrong.
cd = CallDict(
    ((lambda x: x >= 75), "Common"),
    ((lambda x: x <= 20), "Rare"),
    ((lambda x: x >= 5), "Legendary"),
)


assert cd[1] == 'Rare'
assert cd[10] == 'Rare'
assert cd[50] == 'Legendary'
assert cd[100] == 'Common'
```

Comment: Note that I don't advocate creating a `Mapping` object for this particular case. For such a simple case, I'd prefer to see `rarity = HowRareIsIt(10)`. But knowing that one *can* create a mapping object may be useful for other, similar, cases.